# Python subprocess reading stdout/stderr if the program crashes in < 10 seconds

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a script which schedules long runs of a different program that will sometimes can run in parallel (i.e I could call the function below multiple times). I would like to fire and forget about these children so I currently have:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False)
time.sleep(20)
result = p.poll()
if result is not None and result != 0:
    print("Child failed to start with exit code: {}".format(result))
    return False
return True
```

This works well for the most part but I would like to get the stdout/stderr for the child but only in the case that it fails to run for more than 10 seconds.

From my understanding using `Popen(..., stdout=PIPE)` will mean that if I just ignore the subprocess object then the buffer will fill and the child process will hang.

How can I fix this so that it wont hang. Is it at all possible to swap out PIPE for None somehow.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
time.sleep(20)
result = p.poll()
if result is not None and result != 0:
    print("Child failed to start with exit code: {}".format(result))
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    print("STDOUT:", stdout)
    print("STDERR:", stderr)
    return False
return True
```

It is also safe to assume that I can easily hold the output that would be generated in the first 10 seconds in the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to have all the children write to temporary files (https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html).  Just write there instead of to a pipe, and read the files only as needed (if there is a crash).